# How to dynamically change arguments to a process in multiprocessing using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, multiprocessing

I have a code that spawns two processes and the processes run a function taking 2 arguments
I want to check a condition say,every 0.1 seconds and change the arguments to both the processes's target function without having to kill and restart the process. How should i do this?

```
def func(arg1,arg2):
    #do something
main():
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=(arg1,arg2))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=(arg1,arg2))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Answer (score 2):

The main idea here should be not to pass the actual arguments but a communication channel. For **one way communication** (passing new arguments) use `Queue`. For **bidirectional communication** (passing arguments and receiving results) use `Pipe`.
For more information see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes

Following your example code, this could look along the lines of this:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def func(queue):
    while True:
        arg1, arg2 = queue.get()
        print(arg1, " ", arg2)    # sample usage

# create queues and pass them to your function
q1 = multiprocessing.Queue()
q2 = multiprocessing.Queue()
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=(q1,))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=(q2,))
p1.start()
p2.start()

# sample arguments
args = [
    ("arg1.1", "arg1.2"),
    ("arg2.1", "arg2.2"),
    ("arg3.1", "arg3.2"),
    ("arg4.1", "arg4.2"),
    ("arg5.1", "arg5.2"),
    ("arg6.1", "arg6.2"),
]

# Here you would likely have your own way to generate new arguments.
for arg1, arg2 in args:
    q1.put((arg1, arg2))
    q2.put((arg1, arg2))
    time.sleep(1)

# Since the processes now run indefinitly, you have to kill them.
# Alternitively you could send them a stop signal and let them return.
p1.kill()
p2.kill()
```

`Queue.get()` is by default a blocking call meaning it waits until a result is available: https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get